# List<string> Custom Sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, sorting

I currently have a `List<string>` object that stores following HTML strings, mainly the URLs, e.g.

```
List[0] = "<a href='#' id='1'>Banana</a>";
List[1] = "<a href='#' id='2'>Orange</a>";
List[2] = "<a href='#' id='3'>Apple</a>";
List[3] = "<a href='#' id='4'>Mango</a>";
...
```

And, when I sort the `List<string>` object, by doing `URLList.Sort(); (assume that`URLList`object has been instantiated.)`, it gives such order, **Banana=>Orange=>Apple=>Mango**, which is not exactly what I wanted.

I'd like to have it sorted based on the alphabetical order of these fruit, which is like **Apple=>Banana=>Mango=>Orange**.

So how can I achieve this custom sorting? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a simple way of doing it, and you expect your array to not change too much:

**EDITED 11/30/2012**

```
List.Sort((x, y) => x.Substring(x.IndexOf(">") + 1, 1).CompareTo(y.Substring(y.IndexOf(">") + 1, 1)));
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This works great as well. Such a nice and simple solution.

Comment: @woodykiddy Woody, I just realized there is a change needed, in the .CompareTo() you need to use y.indexof not x.indexof. I have edited my post to the correct code. It works with the wrong alias specified due to all the strings being the same length before the actual words, but would error out when you got to id ='9' compared to id = '10'.

Comment: Thanks for the edit and comments. It's been very helpful. I have also added .ToUpper() after Substring() so it'd ignore case.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider turning your `List<string>` into a `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`.  You can populate it with the `Key` being set to "Banana", "Apple", etc. and the `Value` being the url itself.  Then you can sort on the `Key`.

Comment: Hope it works.  If changing your object interferes with other aspects of your app, consider the answer provided by @KreepN.

Answer (score 0):

**Default sorting** for **strings** is **alphabetical**, which in this case is controlled by the `id`attribute, since that is the **first part of the strings that is different**. You would want to use the version of **sort [which takes a comparison object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx)** and provide your **own comparison function** which correctly parses your tag and returns the order. Alternatively read your HTML tag into a class, and store it as a list of these objects, would make the code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This is expected. You are sorting simple strings and the first place they vary is at the value of the `id` attribute.

I assume it's calling `ToString()` to determine the sort order, so you could try overriding that to return only the inner text. But I really think you need a class here instead of just strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to C# and ASP.NET, but maybe you could use a `System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLink` instead of a string:

```
List<HyperLink> links = new List<HyperLink>();

links.Add(new HyperLink() { NavigateURL = "#", ID = "1", Text = "Banana" });
links.Add(new HyperLink() { NavigateURL = "#", ID = "2", Text = "Apple" });
links.Add(new HyperLink() { NavigateURL = "#", ID = "3", Text = "Orange" });
links.Add(new HyperLink() { NavigateURL = "#", ID = "4", Text = "Mango" });

links.Sort((x, y) => x.Text.CompareTo(y.Text));
```

These links can then be appended to another control on your page, such as a `<div>` etc.:

```
Control parent = Page.FindControl("id-of-control");
foreach (HyperLink l in links)
    parent.Controls.Add(l);
```

Answer (score -1):

Because in your list, the string `<a href='#' id='1'>Banana</a>` contains `id` attribute, whose value is `1`, it's smaller than `<a href='#' id='2'>Orange</a>`, whose `id` value is `2`. So the result of `URLList.Sort();` is correct.

I think you need to create your own String class, and override equals function, or implement `Comparable` interface, then override `compare` function.